# GA4 Explore report - Problem with page parameters

Tags: parameters, google-analytics-4, custom-dimensions

I created my reports a month ago and the data was flowing in fine. But today, I get the error " No data for this combination of segments, values, filters and date range. Try editing the variables or settings or remove them. "

This is happening when I try to combine two parameters like a custom dimension and a page path/page location parameter. Whenever I use one of the page parameters(in-built) it fails. This was working perfectly fine even a week ago. Please help

I even tried using page path + screen class instead of query string as suggested by some users on reddit. It works in some cases but as soon as i start using segments in my explore reports, the error comes up again.
Please help as this was working perfectly fine a week ago and my work has come to a grinding halt.